# django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'barcodes' at row 1")

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I'm trying to make a program which take values of barcodes with barcode scanner and save the values of barcodes in db, problems occurs when I try to add more than 5-6 barcodes.
It gives me "django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'barcodes' at row 1")" error. 
I've made sure that its a model.textfield() but that doesn't solve my problem.
My models look like this:

```
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    barcodes = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    to_warehouse = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    from_warehouse = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    total_count = models.IntegerField()
    approval_flag = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    current_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    error_message = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'transfer_inventory'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.id
```

My view function that creates the obj for that looks like this:

```
    def change_status(self, barcodes, warehouse_id, request, is_error="", msg=""):
        barcode_count = barcodes.count(',')
        _list_barcodes = barcodes.split(",")
        print("list: ", list)
        list_barcodes = []
        to_warehouse = Warehouse.objects.filter(id=warehouse_id).values_list('key', flat=True)[0]
        try:
            current_warehouse = UserWarehouseMapping.objects.filter(
                user=request.user).values_list('warehouse__key', flat=True).first()
        except:
            current_warehouse = "-"

        for i in _list_barcodes:
            list_barcodes.append(i)

        list_barcodes = list_barcodes.pop(len(list_barcodes) - 1)
        available_barcodes = list(
            Inventory.objects.filter(inventory_status='available').values_list('barcode', flat=True))

        InventoryTransfer.objects.create(barcodes=barcodes, to_warehouse=to_warehouse,
                                         total_count=barcode_count,
                                         created_by=request.user.username,
                                         from_warehouse=current_warehouse, current_status="Pending")
```

In which specific this part is used to create obj:

```
InventoryTransfer.objects.create(barcodes=barcodes, to_warehouse=to_warehouse,
                                         total_count=barcode_count,
                                         created_by=request.user.username,
                                         from_warehouse=current_warehouse, current_status="Pending")
```

I'm stuck with this error since very long and I don't know what to do. Any kind of approach will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

From your model your column barcodes is **charfield length 255**

```
barcodes = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

You cannot store more than 255 characters as that is what you set as max_length, also it would be beneficiary if you are storing longer texts to change it to

```
barcodes = models.TextField()
```

**And don't forget to migrate afterwards**

---

Other maybe a bit more reasonable idea would be to have related table for Barcode

As you are filtering through barcodes in your code it is much more efficient